# BB10 Simulator on OSX

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am creating an application that should show a message when the network goes to offline state.  But I cannot figure out how to simulate an offline state.

How do I simulate a network down condition on the BB10 Alpha simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the BB10 simulator, but for iPhone simulator I just unplug my computer's ethernet cable.

Comment: I tried that with my wireless connection by disabling wireless, and it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Does the BB simulator have an Airplane mode?

Comment: So when you diable your wireless, navigator.connection.type does not equal Connection.NONE?

Comment: in the simulator, I can go to setting but when I click on Network Connections nothing happens.  Regardless what I set, turn off wireless on my machine, disable network on VM.  It always says "Ethernet"